# Probability Problem on a unit square

Tags: probability

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> A breakdown vehicle cruises along the straight road of unit length that links Newtown to Seaport; help for stranded motorists is also available in both towns.
>   Steven’s car runs out of petrol.
>   If $x$ and $y$ denotes the distances of his car and the breakdown vehicle from Newtown, the distribution of $(x,y)$ can reasonably be taken as uniform over the unit square, i.e. identical to that in Example 1.12.
>   Show that, for $0 \leq t \leq 1/2$, the probability that Steve’s nearst help is within distance $t$ is $4t(1-t)$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhxeF.png).)

**My Attempt:**

So Steve's nearest help is at distance $x,1-x$ and $|y-x|.$ The area of region when none of these occurs given $0\leq t\leq 1/2$ is the area above the line $y=x+t$, which is $(1-t)^2/2,$ the area below the line $y=x-t$ minus the area below the line $y=1-x$ (for $1-t \leq x \leq 1$) which is $(1-t)^2/2-t^2/2.$ Thus the area of the region when of the events occurs is 
$$1-((1-t)^2/2+(1-t)^2/2-t^2/2)=(4t-t^2)/2.$$
I am not sure where I am making a mistake. Perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake was calculating the area above the line $y=x+t$; not all of that region is bad for Steve. You also have to remove the area where $x<t$, which makes a smaller triangle.

---

There are two regions of the unit square where Steve's nearest help is not within $t$. One is defined by
$$
x >t,\qquad y> x+t
$$
This is a right triangle whose height is $1-2t$, so its area is $\frac12(1-2t)^2$. The other region is
$$
x<1-t, \qquad y<x-t
$$
which by symmetry has the same area. Therefore, the probability help is within $t$ is
$$
1-2\cdot\frac12(1-2t)^2=4t(1-t).
$$